# Failed to show calculation steps with sympy and markdown

Tags: python, markdown, sympy, literate-programming

## Question

I want to show the steps of calculation (for example, in text book) in markdown file which is created by a python code. here is what I need in original python code

```
from sympy import *

angle = 60    # this will be changed to created different markdown files

theta = symbols('ss')
x = symbols('xx')

a = Matrix([[cos(theta), -sin(theta), 0], [sin(theta), cos(theta), 0], [0, 0, 1]])
b = Matrix([[x, 0, 0], [0, x, 1], [0, 0, 0]])

print(
'$$',
latex(a), latex(b), '=',   # step 1
latex(a).replace('ss', latex(rad(angle))), latex(b).replace('xx', '2'), '=', # step 2
latex(a.subs('ss', rad(60))), latex(b.subs('xx', '2')), '=', # step 3
latex((a*b).subs({'ss': rad(60), 'xx':2}).evalf(2)), # step 4
'$$'
)
```

you may find that `step 1` lists the common matrix, `step 2` substitutes the element of matrix by given value, `step 3` calculates/simplifies the matrix and `step 4` evaluates the matrix elements to float form.

There are too many calls of `latex` which make the code too long and hard to read.

## First try

I write

```
from sympy import *

class T_Rotate(object):
    def __init__(self, theta):
        self.eq = Matrix([[cos(theta), -sin(theta), 0], [sin(theta), cos(theta), 0], [0, 0, 1]])
        self.str = latex(self.eq)

    def __mul__(self, mat):
        return self.eq * mat

    def __rmul__(self, mat):
        return  mat * self.eq

a = T_Rotate(60)
b = Matrix([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]])

print('$$a*b = %s * %s = %s$$' % (a.str, latex(b), latex(a*b)))

print('$$b * a = %s * %s = %s$$' % (latex(b), a.str, latex(b*a)))
```

but above `a * b` is a wrong answer which is a 3*3 matrix but whose elements are all 3*3 matrix!

so, what is the problem?

## Further thought

In case the above be fixed, there are still call of `latex` function. Any hints to wrap sympy expression so that the python code can be more terse?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Now I wrote https://github.com/retsyo/expand_expression to answer the post partly. **But I am also still seeking for a more common method without supplying every functions by the user**

I released it for it can help others. Here is a example:

If you have defined a function, then you can use it like

```
T1 = T_Rotate('pi/6 + pi/2', useRad=True)
fOut.write(latexExpression('T1'))
```

Is it easy? I think so.